# I installed archlinux through the automatic script and formatted my drive and removed everything from it but it is only 20.8 gb

Tags: arch-linux, partition, disk-usage

So I installed Arch Linux through the automatic script and formatted my drive and removed everything from it, but it is only 20.8 GB my file system is ext4, and I am sure that I wiped everything from it, but my disk manager says I have 20.8 when I should have 465gb in the automatic install script I chose to wipe all partition option.

Is there any way to try to delete the other partition and use it without deleting my current install if it matters.
I am using KDE Plasma and using Baobab Disk Usage Analyzer to see it.

Comment: I run the command sudo fdisk -l and it did list all my drives and found the drive i was looking for but i want to change from the partition i am on to that partition

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.